# Visual Studio 2012 Unit Test - Test Explorer - Running tests and code coverage

Tags: .net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, test-explorer

I have strange issues with running the Unit Test and the code coverage in Visual Studio 2012. I have also the Resharper 8.1 installed (I do not know if it can be an issue)

### Test are not fished

This is my first problem. When I open the Visual Studio 2012 instance and I run all my Unit Test (around 320) by the Test Explorer it works fine. The problem is when I will run it second time. Then the tests are hung. Some of them are completed, but all the time they are in the running state and they never finish. The problem with Test Explorer is that it not provide any details about running test. So I do not know on which test the process is hung. In fact I am not sure that this is a problem of particular test, because I was running all my tests manually (project by project) and all of them where completed properly.

### Code Coverage missing assemblies

My second problem is with the code coverage. It simply does not include all the tested assemblies. The Test Explorer is showing properly all my Unit Test, but when I run the analysis of code coverage on all test, the resulting report does not include the data from all tests.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Can't you 'run all failed tests' a few times to weed out the ones that work? Eventually you should end up with the tests that don't work.

Comment: Helpful information would be if you're doing any initialization for your class and/or method and corresponding cleanup methods.  Also, are you using the resharper test runner or visual studio's test runner?  For code coverage, I'm assuming you're using visual studio's tool because jetbrains doesn't package code coverage with resharper.